# Express.js turn off views only display JSON

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way in Express.js/Node to disable the view engine and only return JSON? The app I am working on will always return JSON

Comment: Why don't you use only define routes that return JSON?  What else are you looking for?  There's no default handling of view URLs that you would need to disable.  Nothing gets served without a route so as long as you only define routes that return JSON, your goal is met.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonData = [{
   "id": 1,
   "email": "1@demo.in"
},{
   "id": 2,
   "email": "2@demo.in"
}];
```

and do this `res.json(jsonData)`, you don’t need any view engine.

---

Sample code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/users', function(req, res){
    res.json(jsonData);
});
```